# Pass array to contructor and store in variable

Tags: c++, arduino

How do I pass an array to a class constructor and store the array in a variable?
I keep getting error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds

```
byte matrix[] = { HIGH, LOW, HIGH };

sources[0] = new Source("test", matrix);

class Source
{
public:
    Source();
    Source(String id, byte matrix[]);

private:
    String _id;
    byte _matrix[];
};

Source::Source() {}

Source::Source(String id, byte matrix[])
{
  _id = id;
  _matrix = matrix; // error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
}
```

Comment: unless your array has a static lifetime, you will 100% segfault your application, use a [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Do you know what `std::vector` is, how it works, and how to use it?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Arduino doesn't have `std::vector` (without installing a 3rd party STL), but it does have its own [`Vector`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/vector/).

Comment: The solution depends on whether the array is actually really global (as in your example), or more specifically: Whether its life time exceeds that of the `Source` object you create. If that is the case, you can simply store a pointer. If the array goes out of scope before the `Source` objects created from it though, you'll have to make some kind of copy.

Comment: Without vector you can  put the array in a struct then just use the struct as an argument.  Messy but works w/o an STL.

Answer (score 1):

For small arrays, it's probably easiest to simply use `std::array` (which seems to exist on Arduino) and copy that around. That way, you don't have any lifetime issues. A `std::array` is basically a regular array wrapped in a struct. It does not dynamically allocate anything — it exists, including all its data, wherever a simple array would exist in its place. It *is* the data. I can well imagine that copying three bytes around is cheaper than passing pointers or references. Here is an example code (I typedef'd `byte` and `String`). Of course, if you have different array lengths, the class `Source` and any functions taking `Source` arguments must be templates, but the change will be simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using String = const char*;
using byte = unsigned char;

class Source
{
public:
    Source();
    Source(String id, std::array<byte, 3> matrix);
    friend void printArr(Source source);
private:
    String _id;
    std::array<byte, 3> _matrix; // <----------
};

Source::Source() {}

Source::Source(String id, std::array<byte, 3> matrix)
    : _id{id}, _matrix{matrix}
{}

void printArr(Source source)
{
    for (auto i : source._matrix)
    {
        std::cout << (int)i << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Source* src;  // lifetime longer than oriData below

    {   // artificially limit original data array lifetime 
        // to this innner scope
        std::array<byte, 3> oriData = { 1,2,3 }; // simple initialization
        src = new Source("someId", oriData);
    }
    // *src has a copy of oriData, lifetime not an issue.
    printArr(*src);
    delete src;
}
```

The program prints

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do is not possible as-is, as you can't declare an array variable without a size specified at compile-time.

What you can do is store a *pointer* to the array instead. In a function parameter, `byte matrix[]` is really just `byte* matrix` anyway.

Try this:

```
class Source
{
public:
    Source();
    Source(String id, byte matrix[]);

private:
    String _id;
    byte* _matrix;
};

Source::Source() : _matrix(nullptr) {}

Source::Source(String id, byte matrix[])
  : _id(id), _matrix(matrix) {}
```

Just make sure that your `matrix` variable in the caller outlives the `Source` object you are creating, or else the object's `_matrix` pointer will be left *dangling*.

Comment: Alternatively just pass in a `std::vector<byte>`.

Comment: If the OP's class is going to store a raw pointer, better read up on [the rule of three/five/zero.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: This is dangerous, especially for beginners, I would consider any of `std::vector`,`std::unique_ptr`,`std::array` a better alternative.

Comment: @Chris only if the class is meant to *manage* the memory being pointed at. Otherwise, the rule doesn't apply.

Comment: You could also use `std::span` in C++20 to have both the pointer and the size.

Answer (score 0):

A safe code would look something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Source {
 public:
  Source();
  template <std::size_t N>
  Source(std::string id, const std::byte (&matrix)[N]);

 private:
  std::string _id;
  std::vector<std::byte> _matrix;
};

Source::Source() {}

template <std::size_t N>
Source::Source(std::string id, const std::byte (&matrix)[N]) {
  _id = id;
  _matrix.assign(std::begin(matrix), std::end(matrix));
}

int main() {
  std::byte matrix[] = {std::byte(1), std::byte(0), std::byte(1)};

  Source sources("test", matrix);
}
```

With C++20, it would be like this:

```
#include <span>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Source {
 public:
  Source();
  Source(std::string id, std::span<std::byte> matrix);

 private:
  std::string _id;
  std::vector<std::byte> _matrix;
};

Source::Source() {}

Source::Source(std::string id, std::span<std::byte> matrix) {
  _id = id;
  _matrix.assign(std::begin(matrix), std::end(matrix));
}

int main() {
  std::byte matrix[] = {std::byte(1), std::byte(0), std::byte(1)};

  Source sources("test", matrix);
}
```

Or semantically closer to your code (storing pointers but not copying the array):

```
#include <span>
#include <string>

class Source {
 public:
  Source();
  Source(std::string id, std::span<std::byte> matrix);

 private:
  std::string _id;
  std::span<std::byte> _matrix;
};

Source::Source() {}

Source::Source(std::string id, std::span<std::byte> matrix) {
  _id = id;
  _matrix = matrix;
}

int main() {
  std::byte matrix[] = {std::byte(1), std::byte(0), std::byte(1)};

  Source sources("test", matrix);
}
```

Comment: Have you seen arduino tag? std::vector is not available for small embedded devices supported by arduino platform

Comment: @Klaus Have you seen "something like" in my answer. Arduino has the [Vector](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/vector/), an array container similar to the C++ `std::vector`.